# Reducing some lines in if else javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wrote a code which look somewhat like this

```
function someName(value){

// some logic here
// the data is coming from this logic part if there is data then
// it will run this part or else it will run next part

 if(data){
  if(data.type !="pdf"){
  anotherFunction(abc,xyz,pqr);
  else{
  anotherFunction(abc,xyz,pqr);
  }
 }
 else {
  if(data.type !="pdf"){
   anotherFunction(abc,xyz,pqr);
  }
 }
}

function anotherFunction(abc,xyz,pqr){
// rest of logic here
}
```

The point is I am calling `anotherFunction(abc,xyz,pqr);` again and again is there any possible way I can reduce my LOC or I have to do it like this only.

Comment: This pseudu code doesn't seem to make much sense. In your last 'else' data is null or undefined, so you cannot check for data.type.
You always send the same parameters to anotherFunction?

Comment: I have updated my question please have a look @IgalS.

Comment: In all cases you are calling the same function with the same parameters!?

Comment: yes @StPaulis calling same function with same param

Comment: Ok, Just call the function... Why you do all these checks?

Comment: function someName(value){
   anotherFunction(abc,xyz,pqr);
}

Comment: as my anotherFunction contain another lines of code @StPaulis

Comment: The same function is being called with the same parameters in all the cases so it doesn't really matter because ofcourse the `anotherFunction` is static.

Comment: There is only one condition where `anotherFunction` shouldn't run, and that's if `data` is null or undefined - the first *nested* if else is entirely redundant and the final else clause is, as Igal S says, a problem - you  can't test the `type` property if data is null/undefined which is what the initial if statement seems to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mainly checking for a pdf type to avoid calling the function, set that check at the begining of the function and return null to avoid further checks.

```
function someName(value){
    if (data && data.type === 'pdf' || doc.type === 'pdf') {
        return null;
    }

    anotherFunction(abc,xyz,pqr);
}
```

Comment: if data can exist and be different than pdf while doc.type still can be pdf you should tweak the condition

Comment: hi there is slit change in my code in both `if (data) and else` part i am checking same `data.type !="pdf"` so will my code will look like this ? `if (data && data.type != "pdf"){ anotherFunction(abc,xyz,pqr);}`

Comment: and why i have to write return null from if else condition can i write function in place of return null ?

Comment: yep, you can do wathever you need there, I was just transcribing your sample

Answer (score 2):

If you always call anotherFunction with the same set of parameters, you may put it into some other function e.g. callMe() and call only that:

```js
function someName(value) {

    // some logic here

    function anotherFunction(abc, xyz, pqr) {
        // rest of logic here
    }

    var callMe = function () {
        anotherFunction(abc, xyz, pqr);
    };

    if (data) {
        if (data.type != "pdf") {
            callMe();
        } else {
            callMe()
        }
    } else {
        if (doc.type != "pdf") {
            callMe();
        }
    }
}
```

But your code does not make much sense anyway, the function is being called regardless data.type === "pdf" or not, so I'm only giving you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Fine tuning @infografnet's answer.

```js
function someName(value) {

    function anotherFunction(abc, xyz, pqr) {
        // rest of logic here
    }

    var callMe = function () {
        anotherFunction(abc, xyz, pqr);
    };

    if (data) {
        if (data.type != "pdf") callMe();
         else callMe();
    } else {
        if (doc.type != "pdf") callMe();
    }
}
```